# allowedOriginPatterns IllegalArgumentException Error

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, spring-security, cors, backend

The class where I set my SecurityConfig settings.

```java
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Where I implement the AuthController.AuthController.java
@RequestMapping("/auth")

```java
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody UserRequst registerRequst){
        if (userService.getOneUserByUserName(registerRequst.getUsername())!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Username already in use.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(registerRequst.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequst.getPassword()));
        userService.userSave(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("user successfully registered",HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

When I send a post request from Postman to localhost:8080/auth/register I get this error. I couldn't find the reason. I am new to java backend. How can I fix the error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.
    at org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.validateAllowCredentials(CorsConfiguration.java:473) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.checkOrigin(CorsConfiguration.java:577) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.checkOrigin(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.handleInternal(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
```

```xml
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

the operating system I am using is Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the error message

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.

Since you have `config.setAllowCredentials(true);` your `config.addAllowedOrigin("*");` must contain a specific URL that is the origin that is trying to access the resource. Perhaps `http://localhost:3000` if you are writing a javascript based front end.